# Convert getdate() to dd/mm/yyyy in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to convert `getdate()` to the format `dd/mm/yyyy` while keeping the datatype `date` and not `varchar`? This is what I tried

```
SELECT cast(CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 103) as date)
```

but it is wrong.

Comment: You don't. The date and time data types have no format; they are binary values. If you want a format, then you sort that out in your presentation layer, not SQL Server.

Comment: "it is wrong" - why? show the output and explain why that is not what you want. this seems like a very unclear question, since it's not evident how a date can have a format.

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Answer (score 1):

The `date` datatype doesn't have a concept of a format. It's just a moment in time perhaps with a timezone attached but without any particular fixed representation. When you format it, it becomes a `varchar`. If you cast the `varchar` back to a `date`, it loses the format. This will be pretty much the same in any programming language that has a native date datatype (or date/datetime objects). It's not specific to SQL.

If you want a particular string representation of a date, then you want a `varchar`, so don't try to cast it back to a `date`.

This seems to be what's called an XY problem. What is wrong with `CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 103)`? Yes, it's a `varchar`, but what's why are you unsatisfied with it being a `varchar`?

Comment: Since relationnel databases (1970 Codd / 1974 Ingres / 1979 Oracle...) are not COBOL's file, every datatype is a real data type and not a character string. The maner you see the date or time is only the consequence of the application you use to views the data....